# Function was deprecated

Tags: c, scanf, updates

I start to study C language, and after a short break, I start to study it again and I'm in stuck with the new updates. This code doesn't works. I can't understand how to do now. If I change from scanf to scanf_s it's doesn't work anyway. I also try to change a declaration of the type. Is someone here who can explain how can I change this code and what to use now, scanf or scanf_s, and on what occasions to use them. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 256

typedef struct
{
   char name[N];
    char surname[N];
    char street[N];
    char city[N];
   char district[3];
    int n_house;
    int day, month, year;

} person;


main()
{

    person s;

    printf("ask name\n");
   scanf("%s", s.name);

   printf("ask sur\n");
   scanf("%s", s.surname);

   printf("ask wh h lives\n");
   scanf("%s %s %s %d", s.street, s.city,      s.district, &s.n_house);

    printf("ask bd\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &s.day, &s.month,     &s.year);

    printf("personal data of the person :     \n");
   printf("%s %s\n Nato il %d %d %d \n    Vive in %s %s %s %d", s.name,    s.surname, s.day, s.month, s.year,    s.street, s.city, s.district, s.n_house);

}
```

The error is C4996 scanf. This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable depreciation, use _CTR_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Comment: try adding #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS just before #define N 256

Comment: First understand the fundamental issue behind the warning: what happens if the user types 257 characters for their name?

Comment: @Firat.Berk.Cakar: You'd have to put it before `#include <stdio.h>`.  But it's a bad idea to mask this kind of warning because it's indicating a very real and dangerous bug in the code.

Comment: @NateEldredge i agree completely but if the poster justs googles the mentioned error, he will get a complete answer. I didnt want to eloborate on the comments or answer a question that already has an answer

Comment: By the way, no function prototype on `main`?  Either your "short break" was more than 30 years, or you are learning from an extremely obsolete source.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using a book and university materials. But I have not studied everything for a moment. In fact I don't know whot is a "prototype on main". Do you means if it's void?

Comment: Try using any compiler other than Microsoft's.  Microsoft has *never* provided a good C platform for learning purposes because it has odd corners where it does not conform to the language standard.  It also has this strange idea that the `*_s` variations on a variety of functions -- its creations -- are somehow more secure than the originals.  They are not.  Moreover, they are *optional* in those versions of the C standard that support them at all, MS implements them a bit differently than the standard, and they are not widely implemented overall, except by MS.

Comment: @NateEldredge he can't put 257 characters cos array provides 256 characters. For this I think it will be an exception.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm using VS. It's always worked before the update. Now it dislike scanf.

Comment: The user *can* enter 257 characters, and if he does so it will overwrite other memory of your program.  The compiler and library functions will not prevent this.  A huge number of security holes in the past 30 years have been caused by exactly this kind of code.  Don't get into such habits or you will be part of the problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok I keep it for the note.

Comment: @NateEldredge I also searched on Google but I didn't find a solution to my initial problem with scanf. I have also compiled with the suggested  changes but it still doesn't work. Unless I define the error as you suggested

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning.

Comment: I repeat, @Ciao, VS has *never* been a good compiler on which to learn C, even if you didn't [knowingly] get tripped up by it before now.  I understand it's somewhat better for C++.  But I'm just offering a bit of free advice.  Do whatever you want.

Comment: "This code doesn't works" because of the input you used.  Post the exact input used, exact output seen, output expected.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your program with some little modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 256

typedef struct
{
    char name[N];
    char surname[N];
    char street[N];
    char city[N];
    char district[3];
    int n_house;
    int day, month, year;

} person;


void main(void)
{

    person s;

    printf("ask name\n");
    scanf("%s", s.name);

    printf("ask sur\n");
    scanf("%s", s.surname);

    printf("ask wh h lives\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %d", s.street, s.city, s.district, &s.n_house);

    printf("ask bd\n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &s.day, &s.month, &s.year);

    printf("personal data of the person :     \n");
    printf("%s %s\n Nato il %d %d %d\nVive in %s %s %s %d\n",
           s.name, s.surname,
           s.day, s.month, s.year,
           s.street, s.city, s.district, s.n_house);

    return;
}
```

And works with the input:

```
ask name
george
ask sur
mac
ask wh h lives
barcelona sskk ksl 123
ask bd
12/13/1111
personal data of the person :
george mac
Nato il 12 13 1111
Vive in barcelona sskk ksl 123
```

Is this the kind of input that you are trying ?

Comment: Yes this is the kind of input. But it's doesn't work the same even with your changes. It's gives to me the same error. I'm using VS like ide.

Comment: @Ciao Did you follow the advice of  [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621292/function-was-deprecated#comment96035313_54621292), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621292/function-was-deprecated#comment96035333_54621292)?

Comment: @chux yes. In this case if I #define crt secure no warnings, it's work. If I change like in this answer it doesn't work again.

Comment: Ok. I consider that the VS is the problem. Can you try to compile in a console-like environment doing with a `gcc` compiler ? Can you know the compile command that VS execute when you compile ?